# My application.js document.ready function is called twice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails application,I am trying to call the document.ready function in application.js script for my auto complete.This function is called twice on reloading the file.i.e even if i don't include = javascript_include_tag :defaults,:cache => true its called once and if its included its called twice. Because of this the value I am passing is replaced with null.Any idea why its called twice?

```
   %td.grid.full_panels
    -table_panel "Assign Testers" do
      %table
        %th Name
        -puts "testers=#{@testers}"
        = form.label :tester_tokens, "Testers" 
        = form.text_field :tester_tokens
        - @testers.each do |tester|
          %tr
            %td=tester.name
            %td=check_box_tag "release[tester_ids][]", tester.id,   @release.is_tester_assigned(tester)
      //=will_paginate @testers
-@names=["sramya","scharron"]
:javascript
var data='#{escape_javascript @names.to_json.html_safe}' 
= javascript_include_tag :defaults,:cache =>
```

My application.js file:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

console.log("inside application");
data1='["sramya","scharron"]';
console.log("before parsing"+data+",data1="+data1);
data=$.parseJSON(data);
data1=$.parseJSON(data1);
//console.log(data1);
console.log("after parsing"+data+",data1="+data1);
$('#release_tester_tokens').autocomplete({source:data1}); 


 });
```

Comment: Is your application.js getting loaded twice for some reason? Check the html source of your webpage

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes firebug may fire DOM ready event like double post to track net. Try to turn of firebug

Comment: Hi in IE if I try it with an alert message instead of console there also I am getting 2 alert boxes