# $(function) gets called twice in Rails 3.2.1 App

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got a Rails 3.2.1 app that I'm trying to include some jquery in.

Here are the files:

states.js:

```
var grid;

var columns = [
 {id: "firstName", name: "FirstName", field: "FirstName"},
 {id: "lastName", name: "LastName", field: "LastName"}
]



var options = {
 enableCellNavigation: true,
 enableColumnReorder: false
};

$(function () {
 alert("hi");
 var state = $("#myGrid").data("state");
 $.getJSON(state, function(data){
    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
});
})
```

states_controller.rb:

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
def index
  @states = SiteIndexPlayer.select("DISTINCT HometownState")
end

def name
  logger.debug(":name #{params[:name]}")
  @athletes = SiteIndexPlayer.select('FirstName, LastName').find_all_by_HometownState(params[:name])
  @state=params[:name]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @athletes }
  end
end
end
```

I'm getting the "hi" popup twice on every page load.

Are there 2 requests going out for some reason?

Thanks

### Problem

Turns out states.js is being loaded to the DOM twice.  I'm not precompiling the assets.  Any other ideas why the file is getting loaded twice?

### Solution

```
ls app/assets/javascripts
application.js  lib     slick.core.js   slick.grid.js states.js.coffee  states.js
```

I'm guessing the `states.js.coffee` was loading the file as well as `application.js`.  As soon as I removed `states.js.coffee`, it worked fine.

Know where I might read up on `*.coffee`?

### Edit

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CapApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [My application.js docment.ready function is called twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672249/my-application-js-docment-ready-function-is-called-twice)

Comment: Where do you include your JS files? Please show your app/assets/application.js and app/views/layouts/ files.

Comment: Or perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107445/jquery-ready-function-is-called-twice

Comment: Have you accidentally included "states.js" twice? (I know that seems obvious, but it can't hurt to eliminate the obvious.)

Comment: Any chance you precompiled your assets in development mode? This will cause all your files to be loaded twice (the precompiled version as well as the individual files)

Comment: Same problem for me, coffee scripts hadn't been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the states.js.coffee was loading the file as well as application.js. As soon as I removed states.js.coffee, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same symptom with Rails 3.2.x, in my `environments/staging.rb` file I had made the setting

```
# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

yet Capistrano was configured to precompile assets, thus I had one copy in application.js and another in the controller-specific `.coffee` file.  Setting the value to `false` resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you "rake assets:procompile"? if y, please try "assets:clean" and run server