# jQuery InsertAfter duplication on Rails form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

The RailsTutorial [Exercise 10.5.7](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts?version=3.2#sec:micropost_exercises) asks me to insert a character counter for the micropost form. I'm using [this plugin](http://roy-jin.appspot.com/jsp/textareaCounter.jsp) to accomplish the task.

Everything is working, except the character count div is being inserted twice, as you can see in the following screenshot.

[image: Two character count divs]

I suspect this is happening because I'm using the `form_for` tag, which takes a block. Here's the page code:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "character-counter", "character-counter-options" %>
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost...",
                              id: "new-micropost" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I can post the javascript if needed, but like I said, things are working correctly except for the duplication. I haven't changed any of the plugin code, just my options following the examples included in the plugin source. All of this can be found in the link from the first paragraph.

---

**Update:** Here is the javascript I'm using. The plugin code is long, so I opted to put it in a [paste](http://pastebin.com/UcPB8sqS). `InsertAfter` appears in line 38 of the paste. My options are also in the past, but since they're short, you can read them here as well.

```
var info;
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options = {
        'maxCharacterSize': -2,
        'warningStyle' : 'warning',
        'warningNumber': 40,
        'displayFormat' : '#input/140'
    };
    $('#new-micropost').textareaCount(options);
});
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the above code. There might be something wrong with javascript codes. Can you post it here.

Comment: @asitmoharna I've added the code. Thanks for looking. This was just the first plugin I found that I was able to grok, but it's old. If you know of another, feel free to suggest it.

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure it out either. I tried a different, [shorter](http://cssglobe.com/post/7161/jquery-plugin-simplest-twitterlike-dynamic-character-count-for-textareas) plugin, and it's still getting inserted twice.

Comment: That means you need to check for the container i.e. the text area id and make sure that there is no other element with that id. Try changing id or a new class. Hope u can get something :)

Comment: @asitmoharna I'm not using that ID anywhere else in the app. I even tried changing it to `#abcxyz123` and it still gets duplicated.

Comment: Not sure.
Clear your cache try again, if still duplicates try with a simple html form then we can zero it on rails form_for as the culprit.

Comment: @asitmoharna That's what I was thinking. I figured out that the js wsa being loaded twice. Now, I just have to figure out where to put the files I don't want in the asset pipeline. Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, since I was including the javascript in the asset pipeline, it was being loaded twice. It was loaded once by the asset pipeline, and then again in my form partial (see the first line of the template code in my OP).

See: [$(function) gets called twice in Rails 3.2.1 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405301/function-gets-called-twice-in-rails-3-2-1-app)

I don't really need the code on every page, just in that partial, so I'll move the files out of the asset pipeline. : /

Answer (score 0):

For one of my application I am using `jquery.char_limit.js`.
It works fine for me.

Comment: I don't want to actually limit the input, just display a character count. I'm doing validation server-side. [This plugin](http://cssglobe.com/post/7161/jquery-plugin-simplest-twitterlike-dynamic-character-count-for-textareas) also does what I want, but it also unfortunately inserts the counter twice as well.

Comment: That means you need to check for the container i.e. the text area id and make sure that there is no other element with that id. Try changing id or a new class.